# Difference between multiple if and multiple and

Tags: java, php, android, performance

I have a query and confusion in it.
Below is example

for `&&` operator

```
if(a>b && b>c)
{
    // do some thing
}
```

for multiple `if`

```
if(a>b)
{
   if(b>c)
{
    //do some thing
}
}
```

So which one is preferable and why? because both syntax and doing same thing. Only difference is readability and code size.

What about compilation time and speed.. Here I am using simple java for example as I am java guy.

Comment: Well, which do _you_ find the more practical? There is not one answer there, and it also depends on what you want to do anyway

Comment: In your multiple ifs, did you mean for the close brackets to be after each if? Otherwise, these are not the same.

Comment: If you want all 3 to be true, the first.  If you want certain parts to be true, then that part of the second.

Comment: And if you don't like the readability problem of a large if with `&&`s, simply split into multiple lines.

Comment: if(a>b && b>c && c> d) this will work when all conditions are true, but in multiple if, if any condition is true it will work for that.

Comment: Who says to both are doing the same thing ? They are not doing same thing.

Comment: You should learn Java basic conditional operators..Search and learn in Google

Comment: ok @vyas so you know about if(a>b || b>c || c> d){} is it ??

Comment: Changing the nature of the question to have it really be a separate question is really just inconsiderate.

Answer (score 1):

No both are not doing same things.  because && approach, if `a>b` returns false, it will not check for `b>c`.

But in second approach, it will check for second/every condition even preceding condition return false.

Comment: I have edited the question please check it.. I was confuse and asked wrong one.. :)

Comment: I always avoid Nesting as much as I can. But if it is at the cost of making my single if condition too complex, I don't mind nesting it out. but In your case, it is not complex condition, so better to use `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

the condition with the && executes if all of the conditions are true and the others execute if the one condition is true

Answer (score 0):

Both are doing different task  first one is equal to ***logical and*** second one is equal to ***logical or*** that is

for first one output is true only if **every condition is true** and for the second one if first condition true then it can execute something under that ithink you understand the difference between them

```
  a>b    b>c    c>d    o/p
  0      0      0      0
  1      0      0      0
  1      1      0      0
  .      .      .      .
  .      .      .      .
  .      .      .      .
  .      .      .      .
  1      1      1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Of them Are not doing the same thing.....
the code

```
if(a>b && b>c && c> d)
{
// do some thing
}
```

will run only if all the conditions are true....

whereas in your other approach i.e

```
if(a>b)
{
//do some thing
}
if(b>c)
{ 
//do some thing
}
if(c>d)
{
//do some thing
}
```

if one condition is not satisfied, than it will not go and check other conditions....

Answer (score -1):

This is the same as difference between :

```
if(a>b && b>c && c> d)
{
    // do some thing
}
```

and

```
if(a>b & b>c & c> d)
{
    // do some thing
}
```

The first one && is short-circuit operator whereas the second one & is non-shortciruit operator.
In 1st case, if (a>b) returns false, it will not check for (b>c) and (c>d). Wheras in 2nd case, it will check for all three if conditions regardless of whether true/false.

In your case, the second block of code is similar to functioning of & operator.

Comment: No, this is not similar.

Comment: I am trying to show the analogy between these 2 situations.

Comment: @vyas: you completely changed the question.

Comment: YA sorry @FlorescentTicker it was my bad.. I was confuse asking question and got -ve fr the same also.. Accept applogies...

Comment: @FlorescentTicker I was the downvote b/c it didn't match the original, but I just noticed this part of the conversation and tried to reverse the downvote, but it won't let me. :( (I'll upvote you elsewhere to balance the SO limitation stupidity.)

Comment: @JeremyMiller Not a problem.. It was so annoying to me too..Wy to waste energy and mind for this stupidity.. :) I YOu can now ans. as voting doesnt mattr really fr me..